Ubuntu - Error message on python.exe when starting new Jupyter Notebook
This error message keep on popping every 3 second when the jupyter notebook ipynb trying to start its kernel, I'm unable to use the jupyter notebook at all. Don't really understand since I'm launching it from Ubuntu, so it shouldn't by python.exe ?  Error code shown is ( 0xc0000142 ).
related info:

conda - 24.5.0
python - 3.12.4
WSL - Ubuntu 22.04

Error Message Shown
Attempted :

tried use conda to install jupyter notebook ( conda base environment )
tried use pip install jupyter notebook as well ( conda base environment )
tried conda and pip install without activating conda base environment

All attempts resulted the same. I didn't change the Python version since it comes with Ubuntu by default.

I suspect 2 people voted to close you because you don't seem to be supplying much for us to go on. We'd need exact commands involved here. And how are you connect the ipykernel and Jupyter and Python? conda doesn't use the system Python unless you link them, which would not be suggested. See here.  Another concern is you want to be careful when something isn't working as you want to not make it worse. If you use Anaconda/conda, you should be sticking with using it for installs ...

and not mixing in pip unless you have something that doesn't have a conda recipe. That isn't the case here. As an alternative to what you are trying in your post, have you tried installing the Anaconda Distribution which comes with Jupyter all set up, with the proper versions that play well together in the base environment.  According to here Python version 3.12.4 just came out a few days ago and so that would be a bad choice for a stable environment.

Thank you! I found out afterwards. Multiple missing packages and stuffs when tried installing through pip. I used miniconda for the smaller size then install jupyter notebook. I use "conda install jupyter" to install the notebook, there wasn't  mentioning that i need to setup the ipykernel though. OK sure I'll look around again.

It seems that the jupyter notebook linked to the conda installed in Windows OS, the ipykernel tried accessing my uninstall python.exe in my windows OS instead of the python version in my WSL, causing the error code.
Tried both removing conda from my windows OS and reinstalling python back to my Windows OS but it causes some other missing file issue instead.
The issue is now resolved by reinstalling conda in WSL Ubuntu, and then reinstall jupyter notebook.

Thanks for posting what helped you sort that. Hopefully it helps some others.
